# Python: Changing value in imported dict has no effect

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.4

Here's a fun one. Create a file `foo.py` with the following contents:

```
OPTIONS = {'x': 0}

def get_option(key):
    from foo import OPTIONS
    return OPTIONS[key]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    OPTIONS['x'] = 1
    print("OPTIONS['x'] is %d" % OPTIONS['x'])
    print("get_option('x') is %d" % get_option('x'))
```

Running `python foo.py` gives the following output:

```
OPTIONS['x'] is 1
get_option('x') is 0
```

I would have expected the result to be `1` in both cases. Why is it `0` in the second case?

Comment: You have two `OPTIONS`s, `__main__.OPTIONS` and `foo.OPTIONS`.

Comment: OPTIONS in __main__ is in locals(), but OPTIOINS in get_option is in globals()

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this because `from foo import OPTIONS` line in `get_options()` function loads a new *local* **OPTIONS** variable in a memory whose value is *{'x':0}*. But if you remove/comment that line, then you got your expected result, this is because as **OPTIONS** variable in `get_options()` is now a global *variable*, not a *local*.

```
OPTIONS = {'x': 0}

def get_option(key):
    # from foo import OPTIONS
    return OPTIONS[key]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    OPTIONS['x'] = 1
    print("OPTIONS['x'] is %d" % OPTIONS['x'])
    print("get_option('x') is %d" % get_option('x'))
```

You can also debug that by using the [id()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) function which returns the “identity” of an object during it's lifetime.

For that the debugging code is:

```
OPTIONS = {'x': 0}

def get_option(key):
    from foo import OPTIONS
    print("Id is %d in get_option" % id(OPTIONS))
    return OPTIONS[key]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    OPTIONS['x'] = 1
    print("Id is %d in main" % id(OPTIONS))
    print("OPTIONS['x'] is %d" % OPTIONS['x'])
    print("get_option('x') is %d" % get_option('x'))
```

Output:

```
Id is 140051744576688 in main
OPTIONS['x'] is 1
Id is 140051744604240 in get_option
get_option('x') is 0
```

*Note: values of id's can be changed on your system.*

Now, you can see the id's is different in both place, this means that there are two **OPTIONS** inside `get_options()` function one is `__main__.OPTIONS` and other one is `foo.OPTIONS`. But, if comment/remove line `from foo import OPTIONS` in `get_options()`, you get same id's at both places.

Comment: Shouldn't dictionaries be by-reference? I get the same result when I change `get_option` to `import foo ; return foo.OPTIONS[key]`.

Comment: @MichaelHerrmann i didn't get the same result after made changes as you suggested. Can you share you changes, to understand it clearly.

Comment: I still get them on 2.7.6

Comment: @MichaelHerrmann i also checked it on 2.7.11+ and on 3.0+. but got different value.

Comment: @MichaelHerrmann the `OPTIONS=` line is being executed *twice*, once in module `main` and once in module `foo`.

Comment: So you can reproduce the problem on 2.7.11 and 3.0? Or not? (@Akshay)

Comment: @MichaelHerrmann the output you got in this http://pastebin.com/bKPJKU7B script , i also got that same result. This is what i want to say that, using **import foo; return foo.OPTIONS[key]** will also give same different value 1 and 0.